# _∷⟪_⟫_ : (x : ℕ) -> min ≤ x -> MinList x -> MinList min

Tags: agda

```
data MinList (min : ℕ) : Set where
  []    : MinList min
  _∷⟪_⟫_ : (x : ℕ) -> min ≤ x -> MinList x -> MinList min
```

any ideal what is << >> mean?

or what the meaning of

`_∷⟪_⟫_ : (x : ℕ) -> min ≤ x -> MinList x -> MinList min`

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three parameters in `_∷⟪_⟫_` which are the underscores.

Number them `_1 ∷ ⟪ _2 ⟫ _3` for convenience below:

The type  `(x : ℕ) -> min ≤ x -> MinList x -> MinList min` has 3 parameters and the result type.

`_1 : (x : ℕ)`

`_2 : min ≤ x`

`_3 : MinList x`

The << and >> unicode are just names, nothing special.  See

http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/agda.php?n=ReferenceManual.Names

and

http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/agda.php?n=ReferenceManual.Mixfix

Comment: Isn't it misleading to call `⟪` and `⟫` names, when here they are only used as parts of a single name `_∷⟪_⟫_`?

Comment: To be pedantic, the names are `∷⟪` and `⟫`, where the first is two unicode characters long, `∷` and `⟪`.

Comment: 2007 Ulf Norell PhD Thesis, Subsection 5.1.1. Names, p.97, calls those *name parts*, and "A *name* is a non-empty sequence of alternating name parts and _".

Comment: So to be pedantic `∷⟪` and `⟫` are used as name parts while `⟪` is only used as a non-reserved unicode character.

Answer (score 3):

Agda allows for defining "operators" (in this case, it's a type constructor) of arbitrary arity (that is, that can take an arbitrary number of arguments), the positions of each argument is indicated by an underscore, so `_∷⟪_⟫_` could be written as a conventional function of three arguments:

```
minCons : (x : ℕ) -> min ≤ x -> MinList x -> MinList min
```

and called as (for both situations)

```
x ::⟪ n ⟫ y

minCons x n y
```